# Make a RelativeLayout at the bottom of a Scrollview

Tags: android, android-relativelayout

I have a TableLayout inside a Scrollview, I want to set a FIXED RelativeLayout at the bottom of the ScrollView=>TableLayout. With that XML code, I have always that RelativeLayout above the TableLayout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:glowpad="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/classement_layout"
    android:background="#000000">


    <ScrollView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        android:scrollbarFadeDuration="1000"
        android:id="@+id/scroll_table"
        android:scrollbarSize="12dip" >

        <TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/tableLayout1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:shrinkColumns="*"
            android:stretchColumns="*"
            android:background="#000000" >

        </TableLayout>

    </ScrollView>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/scroll_table"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true" >

       <ImageView
           android:id="@+id/imageView1"
           android:layout_width="20dp"
           android:layout_height="20dp"
           android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
           android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
           android:layout_marginLeft="22dp"
           android:src="@drawable/green" />

       <TextView
           android:id="@+id/textView1"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
           android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView1"
           android:text="Qualification pour la ligue des champions" 
           android:textColor="#ffffff"/>

       <ImageView
           android:id="@+id/imageView2"
           android:layout_width="20dp"
           android:layout_height="20dp"
           android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imageView1"
           android:layout_centerVertical="true"
           android:src="@drawable/blue" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just encase your tablelayout inside of another relativelayout and then place your "footer" relativelayout below the tablelayout and use the layout_below attribute on the footer to keep it under your table layout

```
<ScrollView>
<RelativeLayout
   stuff...>

      <TableLayout
         stuff.../>

      <RelativeLayout
         android:layout_below="@+id/TableLayout"
         stuff...></RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

In order to just have the "footer" RelativeLayout at the bottom at all times just place it like this:

```
<ScrollView>
<RelativeLayout
   stuff...>

      <TableLayout
         stuff.../>

</RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_below="@+id/ScrollView"
 stuff...></RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Your answer solves the problem at 70%. The remaining 30% is how to fix that layout without the need to scroll down to view it?

Comment: I can't add a layout after the root element ScrollView, it see it like "junk"

Comment: remove this xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" from everything except the root view which in your sample is the relativelayout at the top.

Comment: always the same problem, `The markup in the document following the root element must be well-formed.`

Comment: Also if your xml layouts rootview is a scrollview then once again just encapsulate it in a relativeLayout

Comment: If your seeing The markup in the document following the root element must be well-formed then you must have a syntax error somewhere. Sometimes if youve had eclipse open a long time the UI builder will throw random errors as well. You may want to copy the file on to your desktop and then erase it from your project and then re-paste it back into your project