# How to affix a LinearLayout at the bottom of a screen in coordinator layout?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, android-scrollview, android-coordinatorlayout

I have a situation where linearlayout doesn't stay fixed at the bottom of the co-ordinatorlayout but moves with respect to the scrollview contents above.

I have tried all solutions on StackOverflow but still no luck (ex:[Keep LinearLayout at the bottom of screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46354035/keep-linearlayout-at-the-bottom-of-screen) and even tried relativelayout but no luck: [Make a RelativeLayout at the bottom of a Scrollview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14349716/make-a-relativelayout-at-the-bottom-of-a-scrollview) ). I am not sure what could be causing this, for the linear/relativelayout to move with respect to the scrollview, but if anyone else can figure out what I am doing wrong or missing, that'll be a great help! 
Thanks in advance! Here's my XML code below: (open to sharing any other relevant java code if that helps )

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:clickable="false"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:id="@+id/cl_root_view"
    >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/main_register_container"
        android:layout_marginBottom="60dp"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/activity_register_guest"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:elevation="0dp">


                <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@color/white"
                    app:subtitleTextColor="@color/white"
                    app:titleTextAppearance="@style/Toolbar.TitleText"
                    app:titleTextColor="@color/white">


                    <!--<TextView
                        android:id="@+id/nav_back_btn"
                        style="@style/Body1RegLeftBlack"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/ic_backarrow"
                        android:gravity="center_horizontal" />-->

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/register_guest_main_title"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginStart="18dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:letterSpacing="0.01"
                        android:textAllCaps="true"
                        android:text="@string/register_guest"
                        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.Text.Roboto.Medium"
                        android:textColor="#de000000"
                        android:textSize="17sp"
                        android:textStyle="normal"

                        />

                </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>


            </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

            <ScrollView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:fillViewport="true"
                android:background="@color/white"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                android:layout_marginBottom="65dp">

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:id="@+id/register_visitor_container"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@color/white"
                    android:clickable="false"
                    android:fillViewport="true">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/main_register_layout"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:orientation="vertical">

                        <RelativeLayout
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginTop="5dp">

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/my_location"
                                style="@style/Headline2LeftBlack"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                                android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.Text.Chronicle"
                                android:textSize="28sp"
                                tools:text="@string/five_thirty_fifth_ave" />

                            <TextView
                                style="@style/Body1RegRightRed"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/my_location"
                                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                                android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                                android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/my_location"
                                android:text="@string/location_change"
                                android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.Text.Roboto.Regular"
                                android:visibility="gone" />
                        </RelativeLayout>
                        <LinearLayout
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="28dp"
                            android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
                            android:gravity="center_vertical"
                            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                            android:weightSum="2">

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/select_date_and_time"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:textSize="17sp"
                                android:lineSpacingExtra="6sp"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                                android:textColor="@color/black"
                                android:text="@string/select_date_and_time"
                                android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.Text.Roboto.Medium" />

                        </LinearLayout>
                        <View
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="1dp"
                            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                            android:background="@color/registerUserSeparatorColor" />

                        <LinearLayout
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="48dp"
                            android:gravity="center_vertical"
                            android:weightSum="2">

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/register_guest_start_date"
                                style="@style/Body1RegLeftBlack"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                                android:layout_weight="1"
                                android:text="@string/register_guest_start_date"
                                android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.Text.Roboto.Regular" />

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/register_guest_start_time"
                                style="@style/Body1RegRightBlack"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                                android:layout_weight="1"
                                android:text="@string/register_guest_start_time"
                                android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.Text.Roboto.Regular" />
                        </LinearLayout>

                        <View
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="1dp"
                            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                            android:background="@color/registerUserSeparatorColor" />

                        <LinearLayout
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="48dp"
                            android:gravity="center_vertical"
                            android:weightSum="2">

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/register_guest_end_date"
                                style="@style/Body1RegLeftBlack"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                                android:layout_weight="1"
                                android:text="@string/register_guest_end_date"
                                android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.Text.Roboto.Regular"
                                android:visibility="invisible" />

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/register_guest_end_time"
                                style="@style/Body1RegRightBlack"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                                android:layout_weight="1"
                                android:text="@string/register_guest_end_time"
                                android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.Text.Roboto.Regular" />
                        </LinearLayout>

                        <View
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="1dp"
                            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                            android:background="@color/registerUserSeparatorColor" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/build_your_guest_list"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:textSize="17sp"
                            android:layout_marginTop="42dp"
                            android:lineSpacingExtra="6sp"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                            android:textColor="@color/black"
                            android:text="@string/build_your_guest_list"
                            android:paddingBottom="8dp"
                            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.Text.Roboto.Medium" />



                        <View
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="1dp"
                            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                            android:background="@color/registerUserSeparatorColor" />

                        <RelativeLayout
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="44dp"
                            android:id="@+id/add_guest"
                            android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
                            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                            >
                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="44dp"
                            android:lineHeight="22sp"
                            android:drawablePadding="10dp"
                            android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_add_24px"
                            android:drawableTint="@color/bluish"
                            android:layout_marginStart="17dp"
                            android:lineSpacingExtra="6sp"
                            android:textColor="@color/bluish"
                            android:gravity="center_vertical"
                            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.Text.Roboto.Medium"
                            android:text="@string/add_a_new_guest"
                            android:textSize="17sp" />
                        </RelativeLayout>
                        <View
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="1dp"
                            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                            android:background="@color/registerUserSeparatorColor"
                            />

                        <RelativeLayout
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="44dp"
                            android:id="@+id/search_guest"
                            android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
                            android:visibility="gone"
                            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                            >
                            <TextView
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="44dp"
                                android:lineHeight="22sp"
                                android:drawablePadding="10dp"
                                android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_search_24px"
                                android:drawableTint="@color/bluish"
                                android:layout_marginStart="17dp"
                                android:lineSpacingExtra="6sp"
                                android:textColor="@color/bluish"
                                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                                android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.Text.Roboto.Medium"
                                android:text="@string/search_past_guests"
                                android:textSize="17sp" />
                        </RelativeLayout>
                        <View
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="1dp"
                            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                            android:visibility="gone"
                            android:id="@+id/search_guest_line"
                            android:background="@color/registerUserSeparatorColor"
                            />

                        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                            android:id="@+id/guest_item_list"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:divider="@null"
                            android:overScrollMode="never"
                            tools:listitem="@layout/item_guest" />



                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/arrival_notifications"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                            android:layout_marginTop="58dp"
                            android:letterSpacing="0.01"
                            android:lineSpacingExtra="4sp"
                            android:text="@string/arrival_notifications"
                            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.Text.Roboto.Medium"
                            android:textColor="@color/black"
                            android:textSize="20sp"
                            android:textStyle="normal"
                            android:visibility="invisible" />

                        <RelativeLayout
                            android:id="@+id/text_message_container"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                            android:visibility="gone">

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/text_message"
                                style="@style/Body1RegLeftBlack"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_marginTop="11dp"
                                android:text="@string/text_message"
                                android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.Text.Roboto.Regular" />

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/tap_phone_number_text"
                                style="@style/Body2RegLeftGrey"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_below="@+id/text_message"
                                android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
                                android:text="@string/tap_to_add_a_phone_number"
                                android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.Text.Roboto.Regular" />

                            <android.support.v7.widget.SwitchCompat
                                android:id="@+id/text_message_switch"
                                style="@style/Color1SwitchStyle"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                                android:layout_marginEnd="16dp" />
                        </RelativeLayout>

                        <View
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="1dp"
                            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                            android:layout_marginTop="11dp"
                            android:background="@color/settingsSeparatorLineColor"
                            android:visibility="gone" />


                    </LinearLayout>

                   <!-- <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/submit_users_btn"
                        style="@style/LoginButton"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center|bottom"
                        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                        android:paddingBottom="30dp"
                        android:letterSpacing="0.07"
                        android:lineSpacingExtra="0sp"
                        android:text="@string/submit_visitor_list"
                        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.Text.Roboto.Medium"
                        android:textSize="16sp"
                        android:textStyle="normal" /> -->
                </RelativeLayout>
            </ScrollView>

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center|bottom"
        android:background="@color/transparent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="75dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:id="@+id/fixedSubmitButtonlayout">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/submit_users_btn"
            android:textColor="#757575"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:background="@drawable/textview_border"
            android:letterSpacing="0.07"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:lineSpacingExtra="0sp"
            android:text="@string/register_guest_caps"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.Text.RidleyGrotesk.Regular"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:textStyle="normal" />
    </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

From the code above, the layout I am trying to fix at the bottom has id is: `android:id="@+id/fixedSubmitButtonlayout"`.

I want it to stay intact/fixed at the bottom of the screen irrespective of the scrollview above it which is supposed to scroll behind it ( it does as of now, just the button position changes as the scroll view content overflows screen size). any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: Make _RelativeLayout_ as parent layout and make _CoordinatorLayout_ child of it. And just put linear layout to bottom inside of parent _RelativeLayout_ using _android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"_ and to _CordinateLayout_ add _android:layout_above="+@id/linearBottom"_

Answer (score 2):

Just need to do this steps:

1. add a RelativeLayout  as a Parent of CoordinatorLayout and
2. take out the last LinearLayout from CoordinatorLayout and
3. add it to RelativeLayout with `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"`.
4. note that you need to add `android:layout_marginBottom="40dp"` to your CoordinatorLayout

You can try this (tested and it works fine):

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >

 <your CoordinatorLayout>

 </your CoordinatorLayout>

 <LinearLayout
      android:id="@+id/fixedSubmitButtonlayout"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
      android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
      android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
      android:layout_gravity="center|bottom"
      android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
      android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
      android:background="@color/transparent"
      android:orientation="vertical"
      >
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/submit_users_btn"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:background="@drawable/textview_border"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:letterSpacing="0.07"
        android:lineSpacingExtra="0sp"
        android:text="@string/register_guest_caps"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.Text.RidleyGrotesk.Regular"
        android:textColor="#757575"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textStyle="normal"
        />
  </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Could you please to share your xml contents after try my suggestion? @AngelaHeely

Comment: i copy pasted the same code as yours, only placing relativelayout outside of coordinator layout and last fixed linearlayout inside relativelayout. still no luck, the button actually disappeared since CoordinatorLayout height was set to match parent, replacing it with wrap content didnt do the trick either, for some reason fixedSubmitButtonlayout went out of bounds of the screen

Comment: please share your edited xml contents, I'll fix it for you. @AngelaHeely

Comment: I was able to solve it with my code, will post the answer shortly, thanks for trying to help with this + 10 for you

Comment: Nice to hear it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It will work better in Relative layout

```
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
```

Answer (score 0):

In your CoordinatorLayout, your View must be a direct child and not a child of another View inside the CoordinatorLayout. Then you can add this line of code to it:
`android:layout_gravity="bottom"`

The structure can be like this:

```
 - CoordinatorLayout //(Parent View)
 - - AppBarLayout //(Child View - Toolbar)
 - - NestedScrollView //(Child View - Scrollable Content)
 - - LinearLayout //(Child View - Bottom Fixed Content)
```

Here's a Sample code how it's supposed to be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

<com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/black_overlay"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:theme="@style/Toolbar.Light"
        app:contentInsetStartWithNavigation="0dp"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">

    </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>

</com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

<androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        
        <!--Your Scrollable Content Goes Here-->

    </LinearLayout>

</androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <!--Your Fixed Bottom Content Goes Here-->

</LinearLayout>

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```